# The php operator "->" for reference, doesn't work

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I've come to a weird problem. When I try to compile this code:

```
try{
   throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I get this displayed on my web page:
"getMessage(); } ?>"

Everything after the first `->` is displayed even the `?>` at the end.

But everything seems to be correct, the extension of the file where the code is writed, the `<php ?>` is there also. There's any ";" left behind. The only suspect thing is that in sublim text 3, the `->` is not "recognized". It's working on any other live web application, but not with my WAMP server.

I've tried different solutions like a blackslash `-\>`, but it doesn't work.

Someone can help? :/

Comment: Show us your html where the problem happens.

Comment: You want `<?php` to indicate the start of code, not `<php`.

Comment: Your php is not being executed. Are you running this on a web-server, is the file extension `.php`, etc.?

Comment: Always look to 'view source' in your browser when weird stuff like this happens. There is probably a LOT more shown behind the scenes than what the browser renders in the main view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code to start a peace of php code is:

```
<?php
```

and not

```
<php
```

See [PHP: PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Thanks buddy, the problem is solved, "one space can ruin your life" is my quote for now on.